# Dynamic JWT Token Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I make my JWT validation dynamic? I created a client table in my database where I store its issuer, audience, signkey.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(option =>
{
    option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    option.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = TokenHelper.GetTokenValidationParameters();
});
```

```
public static TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameters()
{
    return new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Issuer,
        ValidAudience = Audience,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String(Secret)),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
}
```

Right now my Issuer, Audience, SignKey are all hard coded inside the `TokenHelper` class.

So how can my `AuthServer` validate token from any client based on my `Client` table in my SQL Server? Thanks